# How to transload a file from URL to Amazon S3

Tags: amazon-s3

I have a 7GB file I need to download and store in a S3 bucket.

Can I transload it directly to S3 without having to download it to my computer?

Answer (score 8):

AFAIK this is not possible. Here's another to confirm this: [Is it possible to upload to S3 by just providing a URL?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3231847/is-it-possible-to-upload-to-s3-by-just-providing-a-url)

You can make it appear that your files are using a different server to be accessed from or uploaded by playing with the CNAME record though: [Using amazon s3, upload files using their servers but URL should appear to be from mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/717663/using-amazon-s3-upload-files-using-their-servers-but-url-should-appear-to-be-fr)
But I don't think this is what you want.

You could however download the file to one of Amazon's EC2 servers and upload from there to S3.

Comment: +1. One of the suggestions given in the first SO thread you linked to may be helpful for the original poster, so let me just repeat it: you can use something like S3FS to avoid the overhead involved in writing the file to your EC2 instance store device / EBS volume. See http://code.google.com/p/s3fs/wiki/FuseOverAmazon